# Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed | While exporting large dataset using maatwebsite laravel

Tags: laravel-8, export-to-csv, bulk, maatwebsite-excel

I was trying to export ~20k datasets from the database using **queue in maatwebsite**. Below code base is perfectly working in localhost. 
But when I uploaded it to my digital ocean server it was giving me
`Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed`  Internal Server Error. 
I'm using Maatwebsite Excel for exporting to excel files.

Export File Codebase:
https://i.ibb.co/yPW3Gr9/screely-1649409743160.png

Controller File Codebase:
https://i.ibb.co/F4cKF7m/screely-1649409670775.png

Please guide !!!

Comment: will that session even work if you are pushing that job in the queue?

Comment: In my localhost, I got the exported excel with the same codebase. And also I tried to send the Session value through the constructor but I got the same error in the server.  Only this error is getting in the server.